# remove a mesh from scene after a raycaster mouse hover event function

Tags: javascript, three.js

im loading a gltf model and i want to have a mesh be displayed only when i have hovered the object.
I have it already change its material color by `INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(radioHoverColor);` and reset after the mouse leaves the object.
But i cant seem to figure out how to get rid of a mesh once i move a mouse out the object..
The mesh just stays on the scene
I trued adding `scene.remove(radioOutline.mesh)` but it cant read it outside the if statement, if i move all the radioOutline code outside the if, it just throws me an error that intersects[0] is undefined which is understandable

I have an example hosted on [github](https://github.com/ziimro/three.js-froppaspin) with github pages integration

```js
        var radioMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0fffAA, side: THREE.BackSide});
        class outlineMesh {
            constructor(geometry) {
                this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, radioMaterial);
            }
        }
        
        // https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html
        // Mouse hover event -> raycaster 
        function onHover(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( radioModel );
        
            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        
                let radioOutline = new outlineMesh(intersects[0].object.geometry);
                radioOutline.mesh.position.set(1.4,-0.5,1.2);
                radioOutline.mesh.rotation.y = -0.3;
                radioOutline.mesh.scale.multiplyScalar(1.6);
                scene.add(radioOutline.mesh);
        
                if ( intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED ) {
                    if ( INTERSECTED ) {
                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
                    }
                    INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                    INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(radioHoverColor);
                    cursor.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    
                }
            }
            else {
                if ( INTERSECTED ) {
                    INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
                }
                INTERSECTED = null;
                cursor.style.cursor = "default";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply remove the mesh from the scene by

```
scene.remove(mesh);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).